# Why is my sprite speeding up a bit after each time I hit replay?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I've include a working snippet below (just replace the red rectangle with a sprite if you'd like to see the full effect; basically, the sprite animation also speeds up with each time that I hit replay). It seems that not only the sprite, but the scrolling speeds for the background and foreground are also picking up speed each time that I hit the replay button (for simplicity, I made omitted the background and foreground from rendering in the snippet since I use local images, but it has the same visual effect as the sprites speeding up. I've double checked how I'm handling the frame count in my player file and that looks fine, the numbers aren't doing anything crazy. Any ideas as to where this bug could be happening?

NOTE: To get to the game over/replay button, you'll need to let the green squares collide with the red square. You'll need to hit replay a few times to see the speed up bug; for some reason, it doesn't happen until a 2-3 clicks on the replay button. And to get a better visual, make sure to view the snippet in full screen!

```js
// Util functions file
const Util = {
  // Find distance between two points.
  dist(pos1, pos2) {
    return Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(pos1[0] - pos2[0], 2) + Math.pow(pos1[1] - pos2[1], 2)
    );
  },
  inherits(ChildClass, BaseClass) {
    ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
    ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
  },
  // Gets a random number
  randomNum(max, min) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
};

// Game file
const MAX_ENEMIES = 10;

class Game {
  // Constructor for game
  constructor(gameCtx, gameCanvas, backgroundCtx, backgroundCanvas, foregroundCtx, foregroundCanvas) {
    // Setting context and canvas
    this.gameCtx = gameCtx;
    this.gameCanvas = gameCanvas;

    // Setting up game objects
    this.dino = [];
    this.enemies = [];

    // Setting game assets
    this.addDino();

    // Setting game state
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.paused = false;
    this.timeInterval = 0;

    // Binding class methods
    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);
    this.keyDownListener = this.keyDownListener.bind(this);
    this.keyUpListener = this.keyUpListener.bind(this);

    // Setting keypresses
    this.setKeypresses();
  }

  // Adding dino player to the game
  addDino() {
    const dino = new Dino({
      position: [30, this.gameCanvas.height - 25],
      canvas: this.gameCanvas,
      ctx: this.gameCtx,
      game: this
    });

    this.add(dino);

    return dino;
  }

  // Adding enemies to the game
  // change time interval === for difficulty level
  addEnemies() {
    this.timeInterval += 1;

    if (this.timeInterval === 20 && this.enemies.length < MAX_ENEMIES) {
      this.add(new Enemy({ game: this }));
      this.timeInterval = 0;
    } 
  }

  // Adding objects to respective arrays
  add(object) {
    if (object instanceof Dino) {
      this.dino.push(object);
    } else if (object instanceof Enemy) {
      this.enemies.push(object);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown type of object');
    }
  };

  // Removing objects from respective arrays
  remove(object) {
    if (object instanceof Enemy) {
      this.enemies.splice(this.enemies.indexOf(object), 1);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown type of object');
    }
  }

  // Checking to see if the position is out of bounds
  isOutOfBounds(pos, type) {
    let result;

    if (type === 'enemy') {
      result = pos[0] < 0;
    }

    return result;
  };

  // Gets a random position
  randomPosition() {
    return [
      this.gameCanvas.width + Util.randomNum(50, 150),
      this.gameCanvas.height - Util.randomNum(10, 20)
    ];
  };

  // Setting keypresses
  setKeypresses() {
    this.gameCanvas.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDownListener);
    this.gameCanvas.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyUpListener);
  }

  // Handler for key down
  keyDownListener(e) {  
    const dino = this.dino[0];
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Array of valid key codes
    const validKeys = ['ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown', 'Space'];

    if (!this.gameOver) {   
      // Prevents continuous actions when key is held down
      if (e.repeat) {
        if (e.code !== 'ArrowDown') {
          dino.toggleDirection('idle');
        } else {
          return;
        }
      } else if (validKeys.includes(e.code)) {
        dino.toggleDirection(`${e.code}`);
      } 
    }
  }

  // Handler for key up
  keyUpListener(e) {
    const dino = this.dino[0];
    e.preventDefault();
    dino.toggleDirection('idle');
  }

  // Storing all moving game objects in an array
  allObjects() {
    return [].concat(this.dino, this.enemies);
  }

  // Updates objects
  updateObjects(ctx) {
    this.allObjects().forEach(object => object.update(ctx));
  }


  // Checking player collsions
  checkPlayerCollisions() {
    const dino = this.dino;
    const enemies = this.enemies;

    for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
      const obj1 = dino[0];
      const obj2 = enemies[i];

      if (obj1.collidedWith(obj2)) {
        const collision = obj1.collidedWith(obj2);
        if (collision) {
          this.gameOver = true;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Drawing the game
  draw(ctx) {  
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.gameCanvas.width, this.gameCanvas.height);

    // Adding enemies to game
    this.addEnemies();
  }

  // Replays a new game
  replay() {
    const dino = this.dino[0];

    document.getElementById('game-canvas').focus();

    // Resetting game variables
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.timeInterval = 0;
    dino.frames = 0;
    dino.gameOver = false;
    this.enemies = [];

    this.start();
  }

  // temp start function for game
  start() {
    if (!this.gameOver) {
      this.draw(this.gameCtx);
      this.updateObjects(this.gameCtx);
      this.checkPlayerCollisions();
      requestAnimationFrame(this.start.bind(this));
    } else {
      const gameOver = new GameOverMenu({ game: this });
      gameOver.draw();
    }
  }
}


// Dino player file
// Constants
const DINO_WIDTH = 24;
const DINO_HEIGHT = 24;

// Creating arrays for sprite walking, jumping, and crouching
let walk = [];
let jump = [];
let crouch = [];
let hit = [];

for (let i = 4; i < 10; i++) {
  walk.push([DINO_WIDTH * i, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
}

jump = [[DINO_WIDTH * 11, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]];

for (let i = 18; i < 24; i++) {
  crouch.push([DINO_WIDTH * i, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
}

// Populating hit array
for (let i = 14; i < 17; i++) {
  hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * i, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
}

hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * 7, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * 8, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * 9, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);

const SPRITES = {
  walk,
  jump,
  crouch,
  hit
};

class Dino {
  // Constructor for dino
  constructor(options) {
    // Setting player positioning and action
    this.position = options.position;
    this.canvas = options.canvas;
    this.ctx = options.ctx;
    this.game = options.game;
    this.frames = 0;
    this.direction = 'idle';

    // Setting game state boolean
    this.gameOver = false;

    // Setting new HTML img element
    // eventually add different dino color selection here...
    this.dino = new Image();

    // Preventing browser(s) from smoothing out/blurring lines
    this.ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    this.dino.src = '../dist/assets/spritesheets/red_dino.png';

    // Setting jump counter and boolean
    this.jumps = 0;
    this.isJumping = false;
  }

  // Toggles direction boolean
  toggleDirection(direction) {
    this.direction = direction;

    if (this.direction === 'ArrowUp') {
      this.isJumping = true;
    }
  }

  // Gets the correct sprite
  getSprite() {       
    // if (!this.gameOver) {
      if (this.gameOver) {
        return this.getHitSprite(SPRITES.hit);
      } else if (!this.onGround() || this.direction === 'ArrowUp') {
        return SPRITES.jump[0];
      } else if (this.direction === 'idle') {
        return this.getIdleSprite(SPRITES.walk);
      } else if (this.direction === 'ArrowDown' || this.direction === 'Space') {
        return this.getCrouchSprite(SPRITES.crouch);
      }
    // }
  }

  // Jumping action
  jump() {
    const gravity = 0.6;
    let jumpStrength = 9;

    if (this.isJumping) {
      if (this.jumps === 0 || !this.onGround()) {
        this.position[1] -= jumpStrength - gravity * this.jumps;
        this.jumps += 1;
      } else {
        this.position[1] = this.canvas.height - 25;
        this.jumps = 0;
        this.isJumping = false;
      }
    }
  }

  // Checks if dino is on the ground
  onGround() {
    return this.position[0] === 30 && this.position[1] >= this.canvas.height - 25;
  }

  // Checks if the dino collieded with an enemy
  collidedWith(otherObject) {
    const posX = this.hitbox().minX;
    const posY = this.hitbox().minY;

    const collided = (posX < otherObject.hitbox().minX + otherObject.hitbox().width &&
      posX + this.hitbox().width > otherObject.hitbox().minX &&
      posY < otherObject.hitbox().minY + otherObject.hitbox().height &&
      posY + this.hitbox().height > otherObject.hitbox().minY);

    if (collided) {
      this.gameOver = true;
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };

  // Hitbox for dino
  hitbox() {
    return {
      minX: this.position[0] + 6,
      minY: this.position[1] + 5,
      width: DINO_WIDTH - 9,
      height: DINO_HEIGHT - 8
    };
  }

  // Draws the dino sprite
  draw(ctx) {    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(this.hitbox().minX, this.hitbox().minY, this.hitbox().width, this.hitbox().height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  update(ctx) {
    this.jump();
    this.draw(ctx);
  }
}

// Enemy file
const WIDTH = 5;
const HEIGHT = 5;

class Enemy {
  constructor(options) {
    this.position = options.position || options.game.randomPosition();
    this.speed = options.speed || Util.randomNum(1, 3);
    this.game = options.game;
    this.radius = 3;
    this.color = 'green';
    this.isWrappable = true;
  }

  // Moving an enemy
  move() {
    this.position[0] -= this.speed;
    if (this.game.isOutOfBounds(this.position, 'enemy')) this.remove();
   }

  // Hitbox for a mini devil
  hitbox() {
    return {
      minX: this.position[0],
      minY: this.position[1],
      width: WIDTH,
      height: HEIGHT
    };
  }

  // Checks if an enemy collieded with a fireball
  collidedWith(otherObject) {
    const posX = this.hitbox().minX;
    const posY = this.hitbox().minY;

    const collided = (posX < otherObject.hitbox().minX + otherObject.hitbox().width &&
      posX + this.hitbox().width > otherObject.hitbox().minX &&
      posY < otherObject.hitbox().minY + otherObject.hitbox().height &&
      posY + this.hitbox().height > otherObject.hitbox().minY);

    if (collided) {
      this.remove();
      otherObject.remove();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  // Removing an enemy
  remove() {
    this.game.remove(this);
  };

  // Drawing a mini devil
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.hitbox().minX, this.hitbox().minY, this.hitbox().width, this.hitbox().height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // Draws and updates enemy movement
  update(ctx) {
    this.move();
    this.draw(ctx);
  }
}


// Game over menu display file
class GameOverMenu {
  // Constructor for GameOverMenu class
  constructor(options) {
    this.game = options.game;
    this.setReplay = this.setReplay.bind(this);
  }

  // Handles user clicks on replay button
  clickHandler() {
    const replay = document.getElementById('replay-button');
    replay.addEventListener('click', this.setReplay);
  }

  // Prepares for game's replay function
  setReplay() {
    const menu = document.getElementById('game-over-menu');
    menu.classList.remove('active');    
    this.game.replay();
  }

  // Drawing the game over menu
  draw() {
    const menu = document.getElementById('game-over-menu');
    menu.classList.add('active');
    this.clickHandler();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Getting main game canvas
  const gameCanvas = document.getElementById('game-canvas');
  const gameCanvasCtx = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // Parallax scrolling effect
  // Getting background canvas
  const backgroundCanvas = document.getElementById('background-canvas');
  const backgroundCanvasCtx = backgroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // Getting foreground canvas
  const foregroundCanvas = document.getElementById('foreground-canvas');
  const foregroundCanvasCtx = foregroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

  const game = new Game(
    gameCanvasCtx,
    gameCanvas,
    backgroundCanvasCtx,
    backgroundCanvas,
    foregroundCanvasCtx,
    foregroundCanvas
  );

  game.start();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* For rendering sprites without blurring */
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

/* Canvas styling */
.canvas-container {
 z-index: 1;
}

#game-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  tabindex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

#background-canvas {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background: green;
  z-index: 0;
}

#foreground-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* z-index: 1; */
}

.overlay-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* z-index: 2; */
}

/* Game over screen */
.game-over-container {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.game-over-container h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: white;
}

.game-over-container button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
}

.game-over-container button:hover {
  background: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.game-over-container.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="application/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/stylesheets/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/stylesheets/index.css">
  <title>Goodzilla</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="background-canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="foreground-canvas" height="302" width="802"></canvas>
    <div class="overlay-wrapper"></div>
    <canvas id="game-canvas" tabindex="1"></canvas>
  </div>
  
  <div id="game-over-menu" class="game-over-container">
    <h1>Game Over</h1>
    <button id="replay-button" class="replay-button-wrapper">Replay</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. In particular, you should output add `console.log(this.speed)` in appropriate places in your `Enemy` class. (At least I assume the red blocks are enemies.)

Comment: Ah, actually the green blocks are the enemies and the red block is the player. Good tip, thanks! I'll definitely try looking at the speed for those lil guys. But for the red block, the player object (which is the Dino), any ideas as to why that speeds up as well?? I believe that Dino doesn't have a speed variable tied to it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Hm, enemy sprites have a uniform speed on each replay; now I'm thinking that maybe it could be the scrolling action on the canvas? (Actually, I believe I took this out of the snippet above so it must be something else...)

Comment: Ah, hm...I just checked the speed on the canvas scrolling as well and those are also uniform/what they're supposed to be :(

Comment: Yes, I meant the green blocks are the enemies. I see the behavior you are talking abut. Each time I click on Replay the move faster and faster. I don't see the red block moving faster, though. For most of my attempts, it just sits still.

Comment: OIC...when you press the up button the red block jumps. And it moves faster each time. (One bit of UX advice: make space bar the jump button as it is a common control in many video games.)

Comment: What is this scrolling action you are talking about? I don't see anything about scrolling in the code you posted here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ah yes, it looks that way since I removed the sprite animations; but the sprite's animation sequence is also speeding up. Ahhh, so the increase in speed is coming from the jumping motion?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I removed the background scrolling from the snippet since I'm using local images/putting it into the snippet was a bit difficult. But it has the same behavior as the sprites; basically everything speeds up (sprites, scrolling) when the replay button is hit.

Comment: Yes, your snippet here seems to reproduce the behavior without background scrolling, so that isn't the cause. I don't see anything obviously wrong that would cause the speed ups. I suggest using more of the tips on the first link I gave to help track down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new `GameOverMenu` instance every time the player looses, and that this `GameOverMenu`'s constructor attaches a new event handler to the same HTML <button> element.

So every time the game is over, a new event is added to the button and when that button is clicked all the previous instances of `GameOverMenu` will ask your game to `replay` and each will start again their own animation loop.

I won't tell you how to fix it, there are many solutions, and now you know the problem, that's mainly design decisions.

Comment: Ahh, I see, so creating a new `GameOverMenu` doesn't mean that I'm wiping all the old event handlers?

Comment: nope. The event handlers will stay until they are removed using removeEventListener or until the target is removed.

Comment: Oh man, all right, thank you! So just to make sure I understand correctly, it was as if I was stacking event listeners on the replay button on top of each other. And when I clicked on the button, all previous instances of the event listeners were being triggered; which meant that each one triggered its own `requestAnimationFrame` loop. And I'm guessing that this created multiple animations in each frame which made it look like it was speeding up?

Comment: Yes exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Your requestAnimationFrame loop is being duplicated on each replay. The result was your positions all being updated multiple times per frame.

`requestAnimationFrame` returns an identifier and `cancelAnimationFrame` can cancel the loop identified by it. So, to fix your code, I've added a property to your game class `this.requestAnimationFrameId` to track the running loop:

```
    this.requestAnimationFrameId = null;
```

and then added this bit before calling another loop;

```
      if (this.requestAnimationFrameId) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestAnimationFrameId);
      }
      this.requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.start.bind(this));
```

This way you will only ever run one loop at a time.

Fun game, I hope you make it a bit easier, or maybe I'm just getting old :-D

```js
// Util functions file
const Util = {
  // Find distance between two points.
  dist(pos1, pos2) {
    return Math.sqrt(
      Math.pow(pos1[0] - pos2[0], 2) + Math.pow(pos1[1] - pos2[1], 2)
    );
  },
  inherits(ChildClass, BaseClass) {
    ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
    ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
  },
  // Gets a random number
  randomNum(max, min) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
};

// Game file
const MAX_ENEMIES = 10;

class Game {
  // Constructor for game
  constructor(gameCtx, gameCanvas, backgroundCtx, backgroundCanvas, foregroundCtx, foregroundCanvas) {
    // Setting context and canvas
    this.gameCtx = gameCtx;
    this.gameCanvas = gameCanvas;

    // Setting up game objects
    this.dino = [];
    this.enemies = [];

    // Setting game assets
    this.addDino();

    // Setting game state
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.paused = false;
    this.timeInterval = 0;

    // Binding class methods
    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);
    this.keyDownListener = this.keyDownListener.bind(this);
    this.keyUpListener = this.keyUpListener.bind(this);

    // Setting keypresses
    this.setKeypresses();

    this.requestAnimationFrameId = null;
  }

  // Adding dino player to the game
  addDino() {
    const dino = new Dino({
      position: [30, this.gameCanvas.height - 25],
      canvas: this.gameCanvas,
      ctx: this.gameCtx,
      game: this
    });

    this.add(dino);

    return dino;
  }

  // Adding enemies to the game
  // change time interval === for difficulty level
  addEnemies() {
    this.timeInterval += 1;

    if (this.timeInterval === 20 && this.enemies.length < MAX_ENEMIES) {
      this.add(new Enemy({ game: this }));
      this.timeInterval = 0;
    } 
  }

  // Adding objects to respective arrays
  add(object) {
    if (object instanceof Dino) {
      this.dino.push(object);
    } else if (object instanceof Enemy) {
      this.enemies.push(object);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown type of object');
    }
  };

  // Removing objects from respective arrays
  remove(object) {
    if (object instanceof Enemy) {
      this.enemies.splice(this.enemies.indexOf(object), 1);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown type of object');
    }
  }

  // Checking to see if the position is out of bounds
  isOutOfBounds(pos, type) {
    let result;

    if (type === 'enemy') {
      result = pos[0] < 0;
    }

    return result;
  };

  // Gets a random position
  randomPosition() {
    return [
      this.gameCanvas.width + Util.randomNum(50, 150),
      this.gameCanvas.height - Util.randomNum(10, 20)
    ];
  };

  // Setting keypresses
  setKeypresses() {
    this.gameCanvas.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDownListener);
    this.gameCanvas.addEventListener('keyup', this.keyUpListener);
  }

  // Handler for key down
  keyDownListener(e) {  
    const dino = this.dino[0];
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Array of valid key codes
    const validKeys = ['ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown', 'Space'];

    if (!this.gameOver) {   
      // Prevents continuous actions when key is held down
      if (e.repeat) {
        if (e.code !== 'ArrowDown') {
          dino.toggleDirection('idle');
        } else {
          return;
        }
      } else if (validKeys.includes(e.code)) {
        dino.toggleDirection(`${e.code}`);
      } 
    }
  }

  // Handler for key up
  keyUpListener(e) {
    const dino = this.dino[0];
    e.preventDefault();
    dino.toggleDirection('idle');
  }

  // Storing all moving game objects in an array
  allObjects() {
    return [].concat(this.dino, this.enemies);
  }

  // Updates objects
  updateObjects(ctx) {
    this.allObjects().forEach(object => object.update(ctx));
  }


  // Checking player collsions
  checkPlayerCollisions() {
    const dino = this.dino;
    const enemies = this.enemies;

    for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
      const obj1 = dino[0];
      const obj2 = enemies[i];

      if (obj1.collidedWith(obj2)) {
        const collision = obj1.collidedWith(obj2);
        if (collision) {
          this.gameOver = true;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Drawing the game
  draw(ctx) {  
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.gameCanvas.width, this.gameCanvas.height);

    // Adding enemies to game
    this.addEnemies();
  }

  // Replays a new game
  replay() {
    const dino = this.dino[0];

    document.getElementById('game-canvas').focus();

    // Resetting game variables
    this.gameOver = false;
    this.timeInterval = 0;
    dino.frames = 0;
    dino.gameOver = false;
    this.enemies = [];

    this.start();
  }

  // temp start function for game
  start() {
    if (!this.gameOver) {
      this.draw(this.gameCtx);
      this.updateObjects(this.gameCtx);
      this.checkPlayerCollisions();
      if (this.requestAnimationFrameId) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.requestAnimationFrameId);
      }
      this.requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.start.bind(this));
    } else {
      const gameOver = new GameOverMenu({ game: this });
      gameOver.draw();
    }
  }
}


// Dino player file
// Constants
const DINO_WIDTH = 24;
const DINO_HEIGHT = 24;

// Creating arrays for sprite walking, jumping, and crouching
let walk = [];
let jump = [];
let crouch = [];
let hit = [];

for (let i = 4; i < 10; i++) {
  walk.push([DINO_WIDTH * i, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
}

jump = [[DINO_WIDTH * 11, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]];

for (let i = 18; i < 24; i++) {
  crouch.push([DINO_WIDTH * i, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
}

// Populating hit array
for (let i = 14; i < 17; i++) {
  hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * i, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
}

hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * 7, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * 8, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);
hit.push([DINO_WIDTH * 9, 0, DINO_WIDTH, DINO_HEIGHT]);

const SPRITES = {
  walk,
  jump,
  crouch,
  hit
};

class Dino {
  // Constructor for dino
  constructor(options) {
    // Setting player positioning and action
    this.position = options.position;
    this.canvas = options.canvas;
    this.ctx = options.ctx;
    this.game = options.game;
    this.frames = 0;
    this.direction = 'idle';

    // Setting game state boolean
    this.gameOver = false;

    // Setting new HTML img element
    // eventually add different dino color selection here...
    this.dino = new Image();

    // Preventing browser(s) from smoothing out/blurring lines
    this.ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    this.dino.src = '../dist/assets/spritesheets/red_dino.png';

    // Setting jump counter and boolean
    this.jumps = 0;
    this.isJumping = false;
  }

  // Toggles direction boolean
  toggleDirection(direction) {
    this.direction = direction;

    if (this.direction === 'ArrowUp') {
      this.isJumping = true;
    }
  }

  // Gets the correct sprite
  getSprite() {       
    // if (!this.gameOver) {
      if (this.gameOver) {
        return this.getHitSprite(SPRITES.hit);
      } else if (!this.onGround() || this.direction === 'ArrowUp') {
        return SPRITES.jump[0];
      } else if (this.direction === 'idle') {
        return this.getIdleSprite(SPRITES.walk);
      } else if (this.direction === 'ArrowDown' || this.direction === 'Space') {
        return this.getCrouchSprite(SPRITES.crouch);
      }
    // }
  }

  // Jumping action
  jump() {
    const gravity = 0.6;
    let jumpStrength = 9;

    if (this.isJumping) {
      if (this.jumps === 0 || !this.onGround()) {
        this.position[1] -= jumpStrength - gravity * this.jumps;
        this.jumps += 1;
      } else {
        this.position[1] = this.canvas.height - 25;
        this.jumps = 0;
        this.isJumping = false;
      }
    }
  }

  // Checks if dino is on the ground
  onGround() {
    return this.position[0] === 30 && this.position[1] >= this.canvas.height - 25;
  }

  // Checks if the dino collieded with an enemy
  collidedWith(otherObject) {
    const posX = this.hitbox().minX;
    const posY = this.hitbox().minY;

    const collided = (posX < otherObject.hitbox().minX + otherObject.hitbox().width &&
      posX + this.hitbox().width > otherObject.hitbox().minX &&
      posY < otherObject.hitbox().minY + otherObject.hitbox().height &&
      posY + this.hitbox().height > otherObject.hitbox().minY);

    if (collided) {
      this.gameOver = true;
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };

  // Hitbox for dino
  hitbox() {
    return {
      minX: this.position[0] + 6,
      minY: this.position[1] + 5,
      width: DINO_WIDTH - 9,
      height: DINO_HEIGHT - 8
    };
  }

  // Draws the dino sprite
  draw(ctx) {    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(this.hitbox().minX, this.hitbox().minY, this.hitbox().width, this.hitbox().height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  update(ctx) {
    this.jump();
    this.draw(ctx);
  }
}

// Enemy file
const WIDTH = 5;
const HEIGHT = 5;

class Enemy {
  constructor(options) {
    this.position = options.position || options.game.randomPosition();
    this.speed = options.speed || Util.randomNum(1, 3);
    this.game = options.game;
    this.radius = 3;
    this.color = 'green';
    this.isWrappable = true;
  }

  // Moving an enemy
  move() {
    this.position[0] -= this.speed;
    if (this.game.isOutOfBounds(this.position, 'enemy')) this.remove();
   }

  // Hitbox for a mini devil
  hitbox() {
    return {
      minX: this.position[0],
      minY: this.position[1],
      width: WIDTH,
      height: HEIGHT
    };
  }

  // Checks if an enemy collieded with a fireball
  collidedWith(otherObject) {
    const posX = this.hitbox().minX;
    const posY = this.hitbox().minY;

    const collided = (posX < otherObject.hitbox().minX + otherObject.hitbox().width &&
      posX + this.hitbox().width > otherObject.hitbox().minX &&
      posY < otherObject.hitbox().minY + otherObject.hitbox().height &&
      posY + this.hitbox().height > otherObject.hitbox().minY);

    if (collided) {
      this.remove();
      otherObject.remove();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  // Removing an enemy
  remove() {
    this.game.remove(this);
  };

  // Drawing a mini devil
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.hitbox().minX, this.hitbox().minY, this.hitbox().width, this.hitbox().height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // Draws and updates enemy movement
  update(ctx) {
    this.move();
    this.draw(ctx);
  }
}


// Game over menu display file
class GameOverMenu {
  // Constructor for GameOverMenu class
  constructor(options) {
    this.game = options.game;
    this.setReplay = this.setReplay.bind(this);
  }

  // Handles user clicks on replay button
  clickHandler() {
    const replay = document.getElementById('replay-button');
    replay.addEventListener('click', this.setReplay);
  }

  // Prepares for game's replay function
  setReplay() {
    const menu = document.getElementById('game-over-menu');
    menu.classList.remove('active');    
    this.game.replay();
  }

  // Drawing the game over menu
  draw() {
    const menu = document.getElementById('game-over-menu');
    menu.classList.add('active');
    this.clickHandler();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Getting main game canvas
  const gameCanvas = document.getElementById('game-canvas');
  const gameCanvasCtx = gameCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // Parallax scrolling effect
  // Getting background canvas
  const backgroundCanvas = document.getElementById('background-canvas');
  const backgroundCanvasCtx = backgroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // Getting foreground canvas
  const foregroundCanvas = document.getElementById('foreground-canvas');
  const foregroundCanvasCtx = foregroundCanvas.getContext('2d');

  const game = new Game(
    gameCanvasCtx,
    gameCanvas,
    backgroundCanvasCtx,
    backgroundCanvas,
    foregroundCanvasCtx,
    foregroundCanvas
  );

  game.start();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* For rendering sprites without blurring */
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

/* Canvas styling */
.canvas-container {
 z-index: 1;
}

#game-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  tabindex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

#background-canvas {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background: green;
  z-index: 0;
}

#foreground-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* z-index: 1; */
}

.overlay-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* z-index: 2; */
}

/* Game over screen */
.game-over-container {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.game-over-container h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: white;
}

.game-over-container button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
}

.game-over-container button:hover {
  background: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.game-over-container.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="application/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/stylesheets/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/stylesheets/index.css">
  <title>Goodzilla</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="background-canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="foreground-canvas" height="302" width="802"></canvas>
    <div class="overlay-wrapper"></div>
    <canvas id="game-canvas" tabindex="1"></canvas>
  </div>
  
  <div id="game-over-menu" class="game-over-container">
    <h1>Game Over</h1>
    <button id="replay-button" class="replay-button-wrapper">Replay</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```